# Pdf file don't load on my application

Tags: android

```
package com.example.bm.kuriotetsuya.pdfviewer;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;   
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        PDFView pdf;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            pdf= (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.tvpdf);
            pdf.fromAsset("oki.pdf").load();
        } }
```

Comment: Please provide more details. Do you see any errors related to PDFView in logCat?

Comment: https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview

Comment: Please take a tour [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: nope.Prolbem is PDFView don't show in xml File!